# Yii2 Why is the date field of a active form not updated on page load when using DateControll widget and MasakedInput widget

Tags: yii2, maskedinput

In a active form field I use the DateControl https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol and MaskedInput widget.

When saving the form the date is stored correctly in the database. When I edit the same form I do see the value in the hidden field tough it is not copied in the masked input field so it appears to be empty.

This is how I configured the active form field:

```
    <?php echo $form->field($modelProjectWerkbon, "[{$i}]datum_uitvoer")->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
    'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME,
    'displayFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'autoWidget' => false,
    'widgetClass' => 'yii\widgets\MaskedInput',
    'options' => [
       'mask' => '99/99/9999',
     ]
])->label(false); ?>
```

I can not find what I do wrong, any suggestions?